# jfuzzylite - 5.0 - Error when running

Tags: java, android, logic, fuzzy

I'm relatively new to fuzzy logic so please bear with me.

I imported the jfuzzylite 5.0 package into my android application. I have no compiler errors, but when i run the application i get the following error;

E/ERROR: [syntax error] expected variable or logical operator, but found Z in <> 
Can you suggest what it could possibly be?

I have two input variables; speed and acceleration value.

Thanks & regards,
Steve

Comment: can you give little more detail maybe your code sample or gradle file?

Comment: Hi Ebuzer, it had to do with incorrect naming conventions being used for the input values. In my case I used spaces for Z AXIS ACCELERATION hence why the error displayed but found ' <Z> '

Thank you for your time though. 

Regards,
Steven Farrugia